# How to make specific shots from movies into posters

Tags: images

I want to find a way to get two specific shots from The Shining into a nice print. I dont know what size yet. Really what i would like to know is how to go about doing something like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not for comercial purposes, but a "fan" project:

**1)** Get a Blue ray copy.

**2)** Extract a frame. You can use the key "Print Screen" running the disc at full screen (on a full HD monitor).

**3)** Resample it at double the resolution with "bicubic sharper" method or simmilar (using Photoshop or Gimp)

**4)** Use that on any program like ilustrator or Inkscape and prepare your fan made poster.

Do not expect extraordinary sharpness.

Comment: Along these lines, maybe wait for the 4k UHD release.